# Can the nodes be dynamically inserted into palette without restarting the server?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am trying to insert some custom nodes at run time in node-red palette without the default "npm install node service" from node-red or manually restarting the server. Is this feasible? If yes, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

A described in the [documentation](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/adding-nodes), nodes can be dynamically added using the Manage Palette option from the menu on the top right hand corner.

[image]

This then lets you search and install nodes into the palette.

[image]

EDIT:

You can control the list of nodes presented by the palette manager by setting the `palette.catalogues` value in the settings.json to point to your own custom list of nodes. You will have to look at the [catalogue.nodered.org](https://github.com/node-red/catalogue.nodered.org) project for the format of the list.

You can also use the [node-red-admin](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-admin) tool to ask a Node-RED instance to install nodes. You can pass http/github urls as well as npm node names so it will install private nodes as well.

Comment: I don't want the user to access universally hosted nodes , but the nodes to be created dynamically on some menu selection from  our page wherein the node red UI has been IFRAME'd. I just wanted to know if I can add local nodes to the palette without restarting the server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though

Comment: That really wasn't clear from the question you asked. I have added a bit at the end of the answer as to how you can control what nodes are listed in the `Manage palette` section to only show your nodes